Asignar a una variable el valor de diferentes columnas dependiendo el caso
tengo una duda.
Tengo una situacion donde no se si sea posible pero tengo:
La variable @ValorDia int
Donde de una tabla:



Valor_100
Valor_50
Valor_0




2
30
0



Quiero hacer que:
Si Valor_100 > 0 entonces @ValorDia = 100
Si Valor_100 = 0 and Valor_50 > 0 entonces @ValorDia = 50
Si Valor_100 = 0 and Valor_50 = 0 entonces @ValorDia = 0
Ojala exista una forma.
Saludos.

Puedes usar la condicional CASE.

Se puede sin problema con un case...

Puedes utilizar un CASE tal como te han dicho.
Si lo quisieras en un nuevo campo seria algo así:
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN (Valor_100>0) THEN Valor_100 
     WHEN (Valor_100=0) AND (Valor_50>0) THEN Valor_50 
     WHEN (Valor_100=0) AND (Valor_50=00) THEN Valor_0
END CALCULADO
FROM Tabla

Si lo necesitas enuna variable, sería algo así:
declare @calculado int;

SELECT @calculado=T.CALCULADO FROM 
(SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN (Valor_100>0) THEN Valor_100 
     WHEN (Valor_100=0) AND (Valor_50>0) THEN Valor_50 
     WHEN (Valor_100=0) AND (Valor_50=00) THEN Valor_0
END CALCULADO
from Tabla) AS T

print @calculado


Como lo mencionan los comentarios, se puede hacer con un CASE sin problemas. Pero de cualquier forma dejo el ejemplo porque he notado que personas sin experiencia tienen problemas en comprender como hacerlo porque ponen la asignación en el lugar equivocado.
SELECT @ValorDia = CASE WHEN Valor_100 > 0 THEN 100
                        WHEN Valor_50  > 0 THEN 50
                        ELSE 0 END
FROM dbo.Tabla
WHERE columna = @parametro;

Esto asume que los valores solo son positivos, pero si valores negativos también cuentan podrías cambiar el mayor que (>) por el distinto (<>). No necesito hacer la validación en las condiciones para 50 y 0 porque el CASE dejará de validar opciones cuando una sea verdadera.
Es importante que valides que solo regreses la fila que deseas y por ello incluí el WHERE en el ejemplo.
